# $(4t+1) (4t'+1) = (4s+1) (4s'+1)$ nonnegative integer solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

From the book A Friendly Introduction to Number Theory by J.H.Silverman :

> Welcome to $\mathbb {M}$-World, where the only numbers that exist are positive integers that leave a remainder of 1 when divided by 4.
>
> ...
>
> We say that m $\mathbb {M}$-divides n if n = mk for some $\mathbb {M}$-number k. And we say that n is an $\mathbb {M}$-prime if its only M-divisors are 1 and itself. (Of course, we don't consider 1 itself to 
>   be an M-prime.)
>
> ...
>
> Find an $\mathbb {M}$-number n that has two different factorizations as a product of $\mathbb {M}$-primes.

$$$$

I tried numerically but it seems there is no example up to 101. To find a solution analytically, $(4t+1) (4t'+1) = (4s+1) (4s'+1)$ reduces to $4tt'+t+t'= 4ss'+s+s'$. I can't guess of any $s\ne t$, $s,t \in \mathbb{Z}_+$; though, how possible to (even to approach) to solve this Diyofanti equation for a general set of solutions?

Comment: What's $21^2$??

Comment: @L, 21×21 = (4k+1)(4k'+1) for what k\ne5 and k' ?!

Comment: There a very simple fact: a number is a $\Bbb{M}$-prime if and only if all of its prime divisors have the form $4a+3$. Now, you can consider $3 \times 3 = 9$, $7 \times 7 = 49$ and $3 \times 7 = 21$: these are $\Bbb{M}$-primes which are not prime. And magically $$441= 21 \times 21 = 9 \times 49$$ has two different factorizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll call a number $M$-prime if it is prime in $\mathbb M$.

$\mathbb M$ is composed only on odd numbers, so every $n\in \mathbb M$ can be decomposed into

$$n = p_1p_2\dots p_k\cdot q_1q_2\dots q_m$$

where $p_i$ are primes in the form $4k+1$ and $q_i$ are primes in the form $4k+3$. Moreover, $n\in\mathbb M$ implies that $m$ must be even.

If $k>1$, then $n$ can be decomposed as $n= p_1 \cdot (\dots)$ where both the component are in the form $4k+1$, so $n$ is not $M$-prime.

If $k=1$ but $m>0$ then $n$ can be decomposed as $n= p_1 \cdot (q_1q_2\dots q_m)$ so it is still not $M$-prime.

If $k=0$, but $m>2$, then $n= q_1q_2 \cdot (q_3q_4\dots q_m)$ so it is still not $M$-prime, since $q_1q_2$ and the other term  are in the form $4k+1$.

The only cases left are

- $k=1,m=0\implies n=p_1$
- $k=0,m=2\implies n=q_1q_2$

and they are all $M$-primes.

The only way to get a number that is product of two distinct couples of $M$-primes is to multiply two number of the second form, since

$$
a=q_1q_2\quad b=q_3q_4 \implies a\cdot b = (q_1q_2)\cdot(q_3q_4) = (q_1q_3)\cdot (q_2q_4)
$$

Answer (score 1):

There a very simple fact: a number is a $\Bbb{M}$-prime if and only if all of its prime divisors have the form $4a+3$. Now, you can consider $3 \times 3 = 9$, $7 \times 7 = 49$ and $3 \times 7 = 21$: these are $\Bbb{M}$-primes which are not prime. And magically $$441= 21 \times 21 = 9 \times 49$$ has two different factorizations.

Comment: Is it really hard to solve (4t+1)(4t′+1)=(4s+1)(4s′+1) for nonnegative integer solutions, as I think?

Comment: A number $n\in\mathbb{M}$ is an $\mathbb{M}$-prime if and only if it is an ordinary prime $\equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, or it is the product of two (not necessarily distinct) ordinary primes $\equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.